# php readfile() strange error message

Tags: php, image

showIMG.php is used to show an image from its path+filename, and contains

```
<?php
$fname = $_GET['file'];
$size = getimagesize($fname);
$mime = $size['mime'];
header("Content-type: $mime");
readfile($fname);
?>
```

I'm calling it from another file like that

```
$cell = "filename.png";
$size = getimagesize($cell);
echo "<img src='showIMG.php?file=$cell' /> $size[3]";
```

$size[3] is displaying the correct image dimensions, what means the file was found. But the image don't appear, only a broken image icon. If I copy the location of that icon and open in another tab in Firefox, I get the error message:

```
The image "http://servername/showIMG.php?file=filename.png" cannot be displayed because it contains errors.
```

What is very strange, since the parameter passed to readfile() was only "filename.png", not the full url. Anybody knows what is going on?

Comment: save/download the url, and then open the file in a hex/text editor. look for anything out of place, e.g. php warnings. If **ANYTHING** is output from your showIMG.php script that ISN'T actual image data, it'll corrupt the file. Just because everything looks fine on the server doesn't mean that's what's being received on the client-side.

Comment: It was saved as a png file with 85.262 bytes, which is 3 bytes bigger than the original file. Opening in a text editor (gedit), both have the same bytes in the beginning and in the end, so I couldn't locate that difference. Positioning the cursor in the end of the file, gedit says Ln 953, Col 193 for both, and everything looks the same.

Comment: Probably useful: http://superuser.com/questions/125376/how-do-i-compare-binary-files-in-linux

Comment: Ok, I could use xxd to see that the file returned by PHP have three more bytes in the beginning: EF BB BF. Any idea?

Comment: It's a unicode [Byte-Order-Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). You probably editted the PHP file in a unicode-aware editor and it put the BOM at the start of the script. Since that BOM is **OUTSIDE** of the `<?php ?>` block, it counts as output and will be inserted at the start of any file you send out. Check your editor to see if it has a "save without BOM" option.

Comment: Not finding it. Any suggestion of editor for php files?

Comment: php files are just text. used ANY text editor, just find one that lets you control BOM usage.

Comment: In Windows I had Notepad++. In Ubuntu, it seems that gedit and bluefish can't do it. But geany could. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can place your answer as an answer, so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save/download the url, and then open the file in a hex/text editor. Look for anything out of place, e.g. php warnings. If ANYTHING is output from your showIMG.php script that ISN'T actual image data, it'll corrupt the file. Just because everything looks fine on the server doesn't mean that's what's being received on the client-side.

---

and given the investigation in the comments:

It's a unicode [Byte-Order-Mark](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark). You probably edited the PHP file in a unicode-aware editor and it put the BOM at the start of the script. Since that BOM is OUTSIDE of the  block, it counts as output and will be inserted at the start of any file you send out. Check your editor to see if it has a "save without BOM" option.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add:

header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');

header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($fname));

Comment: Thanks, but the result is the same.